# Why can't I declare and assign a logic type in one step in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I can declare and assign a wire in one step in SystemVerilog.

Eg.: `wire y_and = a & b;`

I can't declare and assign a `logic` type in one step in SystemVerilog.

Eg.: `logic y_and = a & b;`

But this works:

```
logic y_and;
assign y_and = a & b;
```

Why can't I declare and assign a logic in one step in SystemVerilog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the timing of of the assignment on the RHS.

When declaring a `wire` the RHS represent a *continuous assignment*, so it's a shortcut for

```
wire y_and;
assign y_and = a & b;
```

But when declaring a variable, the RHS represent a procedural *initialization assignment*, and that assignment happens once at the begining of the life of that variable. For static variables, that happens once before time 0. For automatics, the assignment happens once when the entering the procedural block

Answer (score 1):

The `wire` type is a `net`, whereas the `logic` type is a `variable`. A `net` type represents "physical" connections, and thus has no intrinsic value - it is solely determined by the value of its drivers.

You can declare and assign a `logic` type with constants on the right hand side, but not with variables. So, the following is valid:

```
logic y_and = const_A & const_B;
```

See the SystemVerilog 2012 LRM §6.5 (Nets and variables) for full information.

Comment: There is no such restriction. See my answer.

Comment: @dave_59 - that _appears_ to be in contradiction to the LRM. I completely agree with your answer re. the timings, but the LRM seems to suggest that you can only initialise a variable type with constant values.

Comment: I see no contradiction. Section 6.8 says **Initial values are not constrained to simple constants; they can include run-time expressions, including
dynamic memory allocation.** Constant expressions are required for `parameters` and `localparams`.